# Show that the sequence $(⌈y_{k}⌉)_{k}$ is convergente

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let us consider a sequence of the form

$$y_{k}=(1+x_{k}+√(x_{k}+1))/(2x_{k})$$

where $0<x_{k}<1/2$ for all $k$ and $lim_{k→∞}x_{k}=α>0$

Show that the sequence $(⌈y_{k}⌉)_{k}$ is convergente. Here $⌈y_{k}⌉$ is the ceiling function that maps $y_{k}$ to the least integer greater than or equal to $y_{k}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x) = (1+x+\sqrt{x+1})/(2x)$ is a decreasing function, by $0 < x_k < 1/2$ we can conclude that $2 < \lceil y_k \rceil < +\infty$ So $\lceil y_k \rceil \geqslant 3$. Now if $f(\alpha)$ is a non-integer number, so $y_k$ in convergent. But in case of integer $f(\alpha)$, we have two cases, if for some $N$ we have $x_k - f(\alpha)$, doesn't change its sign for any $k>N$, it will remain convergent too. But If we have no $N$ with this property, $\lceil y_k \rceil$ get both $f(\alpha) \ \& \ f(\alpha)+1$ infinitely many times and never remain in one of them for ever!